# Deleting feature[]=logo from .info file, enlarged the whole website font-size?

Tags: 7, theming, .info

During the theme learning I deleted the `feature[]=logo` line from .info file  to check its effect at UI. As  expected it got deleted from the toggle list at appearance->theme->toggle option. But simultaneously font-size of whole site got increased, I re-wrote the `feature[]=logo` in .info, saved, cleared cache, but no effect. Something wrong has happened, has anybody experienced this? I am searching but not getting such kind of issue.

Answer (score 2):

@codenext: Can you paste the screenshot of the css in chrome devtools. So that we can see which css code is creating that problem?

Comment: I just got it corrected. As you asked about the css screenshot, I checked the css through the devtools and found the html { font-size: 62.5% } which was in global.style.scss (sass file). But it was previously also 62.5%, so just I did try to change different %. So as I set it to 62.5% again it got set-up to its normal size. Probably what would have happened, as sass(.scss) transfers code to .css file and then it shows effect, probably at that time some bad code would have saved in .css. So despite 62.5% in sass it was showing something else. So re-writing in .css file did correct that.

Comment: Hahaha! It was nothing to do with drupal! see :)

Answer (score 0):

check this page for a detailed instructions.

[Drupal theme settings](https://www.drupal.org/node/221905)

Comment: Well..I was learning from that page only just few hrs ago. and during that deleted first line of feature, to check its effect on toggle user interface, and ended up in this trouble. ..:)..I am not sure if your are referring something else, but I have real all page and I did not find the solution. You want to point out something else?

Comment: check the base theme - if you are extending another one.